# Неправильный тип данных при вводе в Python

Tags: python, input, типы-данных

Вот код:

```
s = str(input())
a = int(s[:1])+int(s[2:])
```

Проблема такая: инпут будет **[цифра]+пробел+[цифра]**, и, похоже, как только инпут видит цифру он воспринимает все как число, и из-за этого происходит ошибка.

**Как мне указать тип данных который будет введен  конкретный момент?**

Вот какую ошибку показывает:

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: вообще правильнее разделять строку методом split:
"1 3".split(' ')  # ['1', '3']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` в Питоне 2, равнозначен `eval(raw_input())`. Последовательность цифра, пробел, цифра не является корректным Питон-кодом, что ведёт к `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> eval("1 2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 2
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Либо используйте `raw_input()` или используйте Python 3, где `input()` ведёт себя как `raw_input()`. В обоих случаях `str()` вызов следует убрать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
s = input('Введите два целых числа, разделённых пробелом: ')
a, b = map(int, s.split())
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `raw_input`:

```
>>> def f(prompt):
...     return sum(int(i) for i in raw_input(prompt).split())
...
>>> f('-->')
-->1 2 33     555
591
>>>
```

Дело не в типах данных и `input` и `raw_input` всегда отдают строку, просто `input` читает до первого пробела.

Comment: Если я для `input()` введу `"`, то он тоже выдаст ошибку, так что дело не только в пробелах

Comment: `input()` читает строку целиком: `"a b"` (и пробелы тоже).

Comment: @jfs Да, в Вашем ответе правильно написано `input is Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).` - c docs.python.org, но решение работает для 2-й версии